# Heating and cooling a liquid in a test tube electronically

Tags: control, temperature, heat, peltier, induction

I am automating a small-scale laboratory chemical process. One step is thermal equilibration of DNA in about 0.5 ml of aqueous buffer, which involves raising the liquid to 90°C and then immediately cooling it to 4°C, holding it at each temperature for about 10 minutes. The liquid must not turn to ice, but +/- 3-5 degrees is an acceptable range of temperature control. I'd like the temperature to move from 90C to 4C within about 1 minute.

Ideally, I'd like this to take place in a removable 1.5 ml test tube, or alternatively in a 3 mm OD/1mm ID hose, and be simple and inexpensive to install. It's OK if it requires some manual interventionl, as long as it can be set up in advance. This is going to be a device that is set up during the day and run overnight.

My impression is that a wirewound resistive heater would work best to heat to 90°C. For cooling, I've considered heat pipes and Peltier cooling plates, as well as having the test tube/hose immersed in a small water bath that is heated and cooled from below.

It seems like a Peltier plate would not transfer heat efficiently in and out of the tube, because it would be a flat surface in contact with a round surface, giving minimal contact area. But I haven't seen flexible heat pipes, and I don't know if they'd work to bring the tube to a specific temperature. A water bath seems like a fine solution, but a solution that directly controls the temperature of the tube without introducing a source of contamination would be better. What would you recommend?

Comment: hot and cold water sources, two electrically operated water valves and a timer

Comment: Hi and welcome!  To get the non-answer answer out of the way -- there are standard PCR machines already; how does your process differ from that (could it be ran on one anyway?), or could one be modified to fit your process?  As for the question, how fast should heating/cooling be? How accurate the temperatures and times?

Comment: There isn't actually any question to answer. I don't see a question in the text or the title. You should ask a question that is relevant to electrical or electronic engineering. Given that a Lab test set-up for DNA is likely to be many thousands of dollars, don't you think that buying a proper piece of calibrated equipment is likely to be worthwhile especially if your home-spun solution is called into question?

Comment: Hi Tim. The equipment I'm building is part of a larger apparatus that handles a bunch of tedious washing and incubation steps, which a PCR machine by itself doesn't do. Liquid handling machines also exist, but are expensive and offer a level of precision control that isn't necessary for this experiment.

Comment: Andy, good point. I updated so that this is actually a question. This apparatus is not for testing DNA. It would be used for a method called SELEX, which generates short pieces of synthetic DNA that bind a specific target. This process involves a huge amount of tedious manual labor, which I am hoping to automate. Sequencing and testing the output DNA, as you suggest, would not be left to a homebrew device like this.

Comment: Tim, updated the OP with response to your question about temperature change times and precision.

Comment: So are you looking for a mechanical solution, electronic, or both? We can offer comments on mechanical design too, but this is mainly EE.SE of course. Recommending/using equipment is out of scope here (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ), but your intuition for a Peltier / TEC device seems reasonable to me, and there are controllers available.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out which type of device will best accomplish the heating and cooling, given the problem of providing adequate contact between a peltier plate and the tube. I can figure out how to control them and select a specific component on my own.

Comment: Is the 1 minute cooling time fixed or can it be faster?

Comment: Faster is probably better but not a huge issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a temperature forcing system? Temptronic is the main manufacturer of them. They aren't usually used for liquids, but they do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Copying the design of an existing machine will be your best bet. Don't reinvent the wheel if you can avoid it.

Comment: A peltier might work, but they are very inefficient so it requires careful engineering to extract he heat and actually get appreciable cooling. Hot and cold water sources is probably the easiest solution that is likely to work well without a lot of iteration.

Comment: You can buy aluminum tube holders off the shelf for a reasonable price fyi: https://www.e-lspi.com/div-bio-solid-aluminum-block-cham-3000

Comment: Thanks Drew and Hearth. Drew, you're probably right about the water bath being the easiest solution. I may focus on that.